# Curly braces declaring a variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Studying React right now. I am on the stage of Router and found some code in their documentation that I do not understand. (they use a lot of short-syntax operators and other stuff so it is hard to google or come up with idea what it is for).

So here is [code](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow):

```
const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
const { redirectToReferrer } = this.state;
```

While declaring "something" on the left it is inside of `{ }`, why?

Comment: Its called as object destructuring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @RIYAJ KHAN Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called object destructuring. It’s a JavaScript expression that allows us to extract data from arrays, objects, maps and sets. Please refer to link below for more details.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/

Answer (score 17):

for those who are really still confused about object destructuring, I can give an example:

suppose you have an object called car

```
const car = {
  type: 'van',
  model: 'honda',
  ...etc,
}
```

then instead of making a repetition of calling some variables inside the car object like this:

```
const type = car.type;
const model = car.model;
```

you can use destructuring object and write it in a simpler way:

```
const { type, model } = car;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is part of ECMASCRIPT 2015 (ES6). Basically, **Destructuring assignment is a special syntax that allows us to “unpack” arrays or objects into a bunch of variables, as sometimes they are more convenient**. Destructuring also works great with complex functions that have a lot of parameters, default values etc. For Futher information about destructing assignments or es6 features this [link](https://github.com/mbeaudru/modern-js-cheatsheet) helps alot